# How to Add Custom Variant to Material-UI Component (React / Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to create a **custom component based on Material-ui component with additional styles.** 
So, for example, the Tab component has variant = ["standard","scrollable","fullWidth"], and I would like to **add 'outlined' in variant.**

This is my trial:

```
import Tabs, { TabsProps } from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';

export interface Test extends TabsProps {
    variant?: 'standard' | 'scrollable' | 'fullWidth' | 'outlined'
}
```

and return Tab with this variant prop.

```
export const MyTabs = (props: Test) => {
  return (
    if (props.variant === 'outlined') {
        return (
            <Tabs
                {...props}
            />
        );
    }
  );
}
```

But, it is having an error on console when I import this component and use.
The message is :

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `variant` of value `outlined` supplied to `ForwardRef(Tabs)`, expected one of ["standard","scrollable","fullWidth"].

How can I properly add more values in variant?

Comment: Adding custom variants is supported in Material-UI v5. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66970148/9449426) answer.

Answer (score -1):

Include `TabProps['variant']` as your Component Props `variant` and incorporate `'outlined'`.

**Edit**: As mattwad explains in the comments, omit this prop when extending the interface and then include it with the custom one.

Also, I believe the wrapping `return` statement shouldn't be there, not sure if it's a copy/paste issue:

```
import Tabs, { TabsProps } from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";

export interface Test extends Omit<TabsProps, "variant"> {
    variant?: TabsProps["variant"] | "outlined";
}

export const MyTabs = (props: Test) => {
    if (props.variant === "outlined") {
        return <Tabs {...props} />;
    }

    return //...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But still getting the same error message..

Comment: @doobean, you are welcome. The issue is that `Tabs` expects a `variant` prop which is exactly the one from `TabsProps`. I believe the only way to approach it is to define/create a new `Tabs` component (lets say a clone of it), which receives the props the way you want them.

Comment: In order to get this to work, you need to remove the 'variant' prop from the interface before you extend it:    

export interface Test extends Omit<TabsProps, 'variant'> {
    variant?: TabsProps["variant"] | "outlined";
}